# Vertical centering in several columns in longtable

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I would like to change the vertical alignment of the second column in this table (the names of the hypotheses) to be centered, just as in the 1st column.

My mininal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,a4paper,DIV=10,BCOR=10mm,twoside,titlepage=false,openany,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=sc,singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{feyn}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}[c]{l>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.4\textwidth}}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,width=.82\textwidth}
\caption{Hypotheses}
\label{tab:hypotheses}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
\endhead
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{H1} & \textit{`lalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\multirow{7}{*}{H2} & \textit{`lalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec. \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\multirow{6}{*}{H2a} & \textit{`lalalalalalalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\multirow{6}{*}{H2b}& \textit{`lalalalalalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\ 
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\small{\emph{Source: Author's depiction}}}\\
\end{longtable}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing `\multirow` anyway, hence do it once more ;-).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,a4paper,DIV=10,BCOR=10mm,twoside,titlepage=false,openany,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=sc,singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{feyn}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\level}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
  }

\begin{document}

\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}[c]{l>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.4\textwidth}}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,width=.82\textwidth}
\caption{Hypotheses}
\label{tab:hypotheses}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
\endhead
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{H1} & \multirow{3}{*}{\level{\textit{`lalalala' hypothesis}}} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\multirow{7}{*}{H2} & \multirow{7}{*}{\level{\textit{`lalalala' hypothesis}}} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\multirow{6}{*}{H2a} & \multirow{6}{*}{\level{\textit{`lalalalalalalalala' hypothesis}}} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
\multirow{6}{*}{H2b}& \multirow{6}{*}{\level{\textit{`lalalalalalalala' hypothesis}}} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\small{\emph{Source: Author's depiction}}}\\
\end{longtable}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

[image]

The following does not abuse `\multirow`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,a4paper,DIV=10,BCOR=10mm,twoside,titlepage=false,openany,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=sc,singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\level}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.4\textwidth}@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
  }
\newcommand{\levell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}@{}}
  \strut#1\strut
  \end{tabular}%
  }

\begin{document}

\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}[c]{l>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.4\textwidth}}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,width=.82\textwidth}
\caption{Hypotheses}
\label{tab:hypotheses}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
\endhead
\midrule
H1 & \levell{\textit{`lalalala' hypothesis}} & \level{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
H2 & \levell{\textit{`lalalala' hypothesis}} & \level{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
H2a & \levell{\textit{`lalalalalalalalala' hypothesis}} & \level{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
H2b& \levell{\textit{`lalalalalalalala' hypothesis}} & \level{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.} \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\small{\emph{Source: Author's depiction}}}\\
\end{longtable}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Note that `\level` and `\levell` are different.

Answer (score 1):

The `m{}` tabular alignment from the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package (which you already load) was made for this. Change your table spec to:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.1\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\textwidth}}
```

Then you can remove *all* of your `\multirow` kludges:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,a4paper,DIV=10,BCOR=10mm,twoside,titlepage=false,openany,pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont=sc,singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{feyn}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}[c]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.1\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\textwidth}}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,width=.82\textwidth}
\caption{Hypotheses}
\label{tab:hypotheses}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
\endhead
\midrule
H1  & \textit{`lalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
H2  & \textit{`lalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
H2a & \textit{`lalalalalalalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
H2b & \textit{`lalalalalalalala' hypothesis} & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\small{\emph{Source: Author's depiction}}}\\
\end{longtable}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]