# Vertical centering using \longtable together with \parbox and in-table equations with enumeration [solved]

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable, parbox

I am writing a multipage table using the \longtable package, and it includes equations within the cells of one columns. Since I want to preserve the document equation enumeration for later referencing within the text, I wrapped the equations around a \parbox.

The vertical centering is correct in the equations column, but problem arises with the neighboring cells; which I cannot manage to center vertically.

I tried the following suggestions without success:

- [Unable to vertically align correctly long table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598850/unable-to-vertically-align-correctly-long-table)
- [vertically center image in longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457212/vertically-center-image-in-longtable)
- [Vertical centering in several columns in longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196500/vertical-centering-in-several-columns-in-longtable)

I provide a minimal working example here:

```
\documentclass{article} 

% ----- Definition of used packages 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fullpage}                   % To eliminate blank margins around text
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}           % To cancel equations
\usepackage{siunitx}                    % To print SI units
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}              % Provides colors
\usepackage{longtable, array}           % For the inclusion of larger tables

\begin{document}    

\newcommand\eqcolsep{8cm}

\begin{equation}
a = b + c
\end{equation}

\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray} % Alternate coloring of rows 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Change upper-lower margin
\begin{longtable}{ m{5cm} m{\eqcolsep} m{2cm} }
\hline
\textbf{Parameter} & 
\centering 
\textbf{Equation} & 
\textbf{Units} \\
\hline
\parbox{5cm}{
This is fancy description for the equation on the right side
} &
\parbox{\eqcolsep}{
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a = \frac{a}{b} + \\
\frac{c}{d}
\label{eqn:eqn1}
\end{split}
\end{equation} 
} & 
\si{\meter\kilogram\squared} \\
%\vspace{1mm} 
\hiderowcolors
\caption{ Summary of parameters }
\label{tab:params}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

The Eq. \ref{eqn:eqn1} was used here.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would really appreaciate if someone could suggest some way to do it without adding extra packages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cells in columns that use the `m` specifier are already typeset inside parboxes. There's no need for another parbox. I think having one parbox within the other is what is confusing it. Just take out the inner parboxes and I think you'll get what you want. If not, give more details.

Comment: @frabjous, thanks :). This solved the issue! I did not know that the specifier m already includes a parbox.